# PHP: ksort return wrong result if use 0 before number

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
$array = [
    'd 01 x'=>'b',
    'd 3 x'=>'a',
    'd 02 x'=>'b',
    'd 9 x'=>'b',
    'd 8 x'=>'b',
    'd 07 x'=>'b',
    'd 10 x'=>'b'
];

ksort($array);
print_r($array);
```

And this is result:

```
Array ( [d 01 x] => b [d 02 x] => b [d 07 x] => b [d 10 x] => b [d 3 x] => a [d 8 x] => b [d 9 x] => b )
```

Why after `d 02 x` not showing `d 3 x`?

How I can fix it?

Thank you

Comment: because 0 is prior to 3. On sorting functions you should be aware of the type of the key and how it behaves. Consider loop over the keys and make sure that are no leading zeros. Then, it might work.

Comment: You are sorting strings, not numbers

Comment: How i can fix it? i want show d3x before d07x

Comment: Consider loop over the keys and make sure that are no leading zeros. Then, it might work. OR write a custom sorting function that fits your criterias.

Comment: Why do you have leading zeros for some entries and not others i.e.  'd 01 x' and not 'd 03 x'. You are inconsistent in your string key format.

Comment: https://www.php.net/natsort, just a suggestion. Anyhow, it's lexical sorting, not numeric sorting and there 02 comes before 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely want to use [uksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) for this. uksort allows you to supply your own function which it will use for sorting.

The following piece of code first defines a function to transform the string key into it's integer representation, and compares the two supplied items by using the space ship operator.

```
function toInt($element)
{
    return (int)str_replace(['d', ' ', 'x'], '', $element);
}

uksort($array, function ($first, $second) {
    $f = toInt($first);
    $s = toInt($second);

    return $f <=> $s;
});

print_r($array);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [d 01 x] => b
    [d 02 x] => b
    [d 3 x] => a
    [d 07 x] => b
    [d 8 x] => b
    [d 9 x] => b
    [d 10 x] => b
)
```

Comment: You're just sorting by the integer. Is it safe to assume that the leading and trailing characters are fixed?

Comment: Just in case there's more than `d x` you can `preg_replace('/[^0-9]/'` or `\d`.